# What is the value of this given series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Here is the question that someone gave to me.

> Find the value $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1} ^ {\infty}\left( {2 \over (2n+1)} - {1 \over (n+1)}\right)$
>   
> (Hint :  $\ln(1+x)= x - {x^2 \over 2} + {x^3 \over 3} - {x^4 \over 4} +\dots$ And the series is convergent.)

Here is my attempt.

Since the series is absolute converge since  by ${2 \over (2n+1)} - {1 \over (n+1)} >0$

Hence Value of it and its rearranged series would be equal

Therefore $\left({2 \over 3} - {1 \over 2} \right) + \left({2 \over 5} - {1 \over 3}\right) + \left({2 \over 7} - {1 \over 4} \right)+\dots $
= $- {1 \over 2} + {1 \over 3} - {1 \over 4} + {1 \over 5}-... = 1 - \ln2$

But he said I was wrong  and suggested his solution

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1} ^ {\infty}\left( {2 \over (2n+1)} - {1 \over (n+1)}\right) $

=$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1} ^ {\infty} \left({2 \over (2n+1)} - {2 \over 2(n+1)}\right)$

= $2\left({1 \over 3} - {1 \over 4} + {1 \over 5} - {1 \over 6}+...\right)$

= $2 \ln2 - 1$

So my question is....

It's really doubt the question he suggested is right or not. Still, I can't exactly know which point  was wrong. If his question is right,  Please tell me What the point do I have a mistake.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you cannot rearrange a series that you dont knows if converges absolutely

Comment: Since  the all the terms of the series are positive, so does it absolutely converge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see what happens,
look at the sum of the
first $m$ terms.

$\begin{array}\\
s(m)
&=\sum_{n=1} ^ {m}( {2 \over (2n+1)} - {1 \over (n+1)})\\
&=\sum_{n=1} ^ {m}( {2(n+1)-(2n+1) \over (n+1)(2n+1)})\\
&=\sum_{n=1} ^ {m}{1 \over (n+1)(2n+1)}\\
&=\sum_{n=2} ^ {m+1}{1 \over n(2n-1)}\\
\end{array}
$

and this converges absolutely.

Also

$\begin{array}\\
s(m)
&=\sum_{n=1} ^ {m}( {2 \over (2n+1)} - {1 \over (n+1)})\\
&=\sum_{n=1} ^ {m} {2 \over (2n+1)} - \sum_{n=1} ^ {m}{1 \over (n+1)}\\
&=\sum_{n=1} ^ {m} {2 \over (2n+1)} - \sum_{n=1} ^ {m}{2 \over (2n+2)}\\
&=\sum_{n=3} ^ {2m+2} {2(-1)^{n+1} \over n}\\
&=2\sum_{n=3} ^ {2m+2} {(-1)^{n+1} \over n}\\
&=2(-1+\frac12+\sum_{n=1} ^ {2m+2} {(-1)^{n+1} \over n})\\
&\to 2(-\frac12+\ln(2))\\
&=-1+ 2\ln(2)\\
\end{array}
$